# angular-ui: can't set tab to active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I get the angular error:

```
Error: l is not a function
.compile/</<@http://localhost/investui/app/vendor/uibootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.min.js:1
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js:8811
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js:9012
done@http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js:10265
completeRequest@http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js:10449
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js:10407

http://localhost/investui/app/lib/angular.js
Line 6349
```

I'm trying to dynamically set the tab active. Using the tabset of bootstrap from [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

Controller:

```
$scope.sectorIndustryActive = 0;
$scope.isSectorIndustryActive = function(sectorIndustry) {
    return sectorIndustry.id == $scope.sectorIndustryActive;
};

$scope.sectorIndustries = sectorsFctr.get();
```

Template:

```
    <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="sectorIndustry in sectorIndustries" 
             heading="{{ sectorIndustry.name }}" 
             active="isSectorIndustryActive(sectorIndustry)">
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this discussion on Github:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611

active can only point to a variable on scope, it cannot evaluate a function call.

So, you would need to set up a variable on scope (or an array) for each of your sectorIndustries, and point the active property at that.